# How to Check if file pattern exist in C# SSIS package

Tags: c#, ssis

I'm new to SSIS.

I receive a file that can be either `CSV` or `ZIP` format which I do not know in advance.

What I want to do is to check the file format and process it accordingly.

This file come in daily and the filename is in the format `PICyyyymmdd.EXT` such as `PIC20171201.csv`

I have watched this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qgqyQm6EymU). This is for a particular filename that never changes.

I created variables called `@FolderPath`, `@CsvFileExtension`, and `@FileExistFlg`.

The script task in `SSIS`, using the following code: the commented part is from the YouTube link.

```
public void Main()
    {
        // TODO: Add your code here

        //string filefullpath = Dts.Variables["User::FolderPath"].Value.ToString() + Dts.Variables["User::CsvFileExtension"].Value.ToString();
        // if (
        //     File.Exists(filefullpath))
        // {
        //     Dts.Variables["User::FileExistsFlg"].Value = 1;
        //  }

        string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("User::FolderPath", "User::CsvFileExtension", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        if (files.Length > 0)
        {
            Dts.Variables["User::FileExistsFlg"].Value = 1;
        }

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

Comment: I just answered this yesterday. Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47788603/ssis-for-loop-stopped-working/47792411#47792411 and look at code no2. This you can use for both checking for *.csv and to check for *zip or whatever you need

Comment: @plaidDK Thanks the link you give solved it